# Is it possible to set the inner HTML of an element with a file using d3js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to clean up some code that I am writing and I had a thought: Would it be possible to set the inner HTML of a component using d3js like the code below?

```js
d3.select("body").append("div").html(d3.html("../components/modal.html"));
```

If this is possible, what is needed to make it work, because right now, this only puts a text field on the page that says `[object Promise]`

Is this only wishful thinking?

EDIT: I am using Bootstrap 5 to implement my modal

UPDATE:
As I described in a comment below, I took the code from @SmokeyShakers answer---

```js
d3.html("../components/modal.html").then((data) => {
      d3.select("body").append("div").html(data)
    })
```

---and replaced the first `.html(...)` with `.text(...)` as so:

```js
d3.text("../components/modal.html").then((data) => {
      d3.select("body").append("div").html(data)
    })
```

This made it so that the modal would actually render, but the buttons and other functionalities I had built into the modal wouldn't work. And for additional information, my modal buttons did not have an `onclick="..."` attribute in the inline HTML, but it was added using

```js
d3.select('#my-modal-submit').on('click', ()=>{...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.  d3.html is a fetch, so I think you need to go inside out:

```js
    d3.html("../components/modal.html").then((data) => {
      d3.select("body").append("div").html(data)
    })
```

Comment: well, it now displays `[object HTMLDocument]` which is different, but not the desired result... I logged the output and it is adding `<html>` , `<head>`, and `<body>` tags around the `<div>` that contains my modal

Comment: I found that if I use `data.body.div` I am able to access the div for the modal, but it either throws me a Bootstrap error (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')`)  or a d3 error (`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`) depending on if I add the Bootstrap class and id in the component file or after the append before the html

Comment: I changed `d3.html` to `d3.text` and the modal renders now, but there is no longer any functionality with the input fields... I'm getting closer though!